# Get plug-in info and how update them?

Tags: nativescript

I've got these plug-ins in my project

babel-traverse
babel-types
babylon

How do I update these to the latest?

Including typescript plugin.

In my node_modules folder - i've got a bunch of entries that I did not install

adm-zip
inflight
minimatch
lazy
mkdirp

and others - anyone how how it got there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `npm outdated` shows outdated packages. `npm update` updates packages. And you need to check the versions listed in package.json to see if they're locked at specific version or if you allow minor/major bumps when running install. There are hundreds of tutorials on using npm and understanding the package.json. those packages you mention, I wouldn't mess with too much. those are added by nativescript to make things work in a sense. So they're dependencies for nativescript they don't actually get packaged with your app (I don't believe, haven't checked that in a build to be certain).

Comment: Dev-dependencies don't get packaged in your resulting build.